# Running 2/0 Individual feeder wires through a mix of SCH40 PVC and LiquidTight Flexible Conduit

Tags: electrical

I need to run a feeder cable (3 individual 2/0 Al for HOT/NEU and one 6AWG Cu for ground) from an external main panel to a subpanel inside the house.

The wires need to enter the crawl space before entering the house through bottom plate to reach the subpanel.  The external run is being done with 2 inch SCH40 PVC conduit. But as soon as you enter the crawlspace, there are far too many obstructions to do a straight PVC run. Even if I use conduit bodies and junction boxes to get around the 360 degree rule, it's quite complicated.

So my questions is whether I can use liquid tight flexible conduit in the crawlspace. I will properly support it with metal/pvc hanger strapping to the floor joists. But is this transition allowed by the code? It will make my life so much easier if this is code compliant.

If this is indeed allowed, what is the best way to connect the two types of conduits?

Comment: If the routing is reasonably protected, smurf tube should suffice.  aka ENT.   You may want that pulling point, though - when flexible conduit is floppy-doppy, pulling forces increase.

Comment: If the 360 rule is a problem for PVC (which is nice and slippery and easy to pull in) it's going to be twice as bad for liquidtight (which is sticky miserable [bleep] to pull in.) You don't get a magical pass on 360 when using that - quite the opposite.

Comment: In most cases the external part needs to be Sch 80 for "protection from damage" as in most cases the external part will be considered "exposed to damage" if it's not above 8 feet or buried. All kinds of fun if the inspector shows up after you fought your wires into the Sch 40 and tells you to change the conduit to Sch. 80....

Comment: @Ecnerwal The inspector cleared me for using SCH40 when issuing the permit. The area is in my side yard enclosed by fence. Nothing more than foot traffic there. Also, thanks for reminding me about how difficult flexible conduit is for pulling cables. I now remember it from a previous project.

Comment: There may only be foot traffic, but there's also lawn mower traffic, and (possibly) kids with soccer balls/baseball bats traffic, too. These things all need the extra strength of Sch 80 to protect against, but if you've got it _in writing_ that the inspector will approve Sch 40, you'll pass your inspection, but might not pass "the real world".

Comment: Can you transition to a cable wiring method at an exterior box?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel You mean do the inside run using a 3 conductor + ground 2/0 cable as opposed to individual 2/0 wires?  I would rather not because I already bought 200 ft of 2/0 Al spool.

Comment: @cryptic0 fair enough then

Answer (score 2):

You can do this ***if you use the correct pipe fittings***. You cannot just glue the liquid tite into a sch. 40 PVC coupling.

The best connection would be into a large junction box (which you could use as just a pull can).

Otherwise, without the j-box, you would need to get a fitting that is certified for use with the liquid tite and would end in either male or female threads and attach that to either a male or female rigid PVC adapter. This might make you wire pull more difficult- hence the j-box suggestion.